# Gnuplot 4.4 axis offset problem

Tags: ubuntu, gnuplot

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 11.04 and Gnuplot 4.4, and find that axis label offsets no longer work. I get the following error message:

```
set ylabel "Speed" 2
                   ^
"graph1.plt", line 17: ';' expected
```

(Putting in the semicolon doesn't help.) Is there perhaps now another way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
set ylabel "Speed" offset 2
```